# How to inherit css animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, html

I have 2 div's. div a and div b. I used jquery .append() to parent div b to div a. How can I make div b inherit all of div a's css animations?

Comment: Can you show what your final markup looks like? And your current CSS? What have you tried? If its something like `<div id="a"><div id="b"></div></div>` you can write a CSS rule along the lines of `#a, #b { /* Your CSS transitions */ }`

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$('div').css($(this).parent().css());
```

Comment: Nice, one line of code to do the job.  If only all solutions were this simple.  :)

Comment: @cereallarceny Ahh the joys of using JQuery.

Comment: @David Ayeke: this was a good response, mark it correct to help others out in the future who view this question!

Comment: This inherits everything, which may or may not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your animations to a CSS class name and give each of your two objects the same class name.  Then, they don't even have to be parent/child relationship to both inherit the exact same CSS animations.

Comment: While the post above does the trick, this solution will be much easier to maintain and allow you greater control over what gets inherited. Check out Jonathan Snook's SMACSS patterns for a good overview of this.